# Microsoft Excel adding up the number of YES's

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In my Microsoft Excel file, I have a column like this:

```
YES
NO
YES
YES
YES
NO
YES
YES
```

In a separate cell, using an equation or something, I want to count up the number of YESs in that column. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this really belongs on a programming forum....  But:

```
COUNTIF(<range>, "YES")
```

should do it.

Comment: this should be accepted

Answer (score 2):

You can just use this:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, "YES")
```